# How to set up secure cockroachdb on Kubernetes to be accessible from NodeJs

Tags: kubernetes, pg, cockroachdb

I am a newbie with both Kubernetes and CockroachDB. I have a secured multinode node database running on a Kubernetes cluster and have been able to expose it externally and monitor it using the cockroach UI.

[image: service list]

Now I want to access it from a node app using either pg for Node or sequelize. However I get connection timeouts.

I believe I have to create a client certificate and use it to make the connection but I can find no Kubernetes specific docs on how to do this.
If anyone has succeeded with this, how did you create the cert, and how did you use it in your node app?

Comment: How did you deploy cockroach? There's a helm chart for it. Are you deploying your node app into the same cluster?

Comment: Your app needs to run in the same kubernetes cluster to get client certificates ([see docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html#step-6-test-the-cluster)), or you can run with `sslmode=require` (warning: not MITM protection with that mode).

Comment: I used the method documented by cockroach. https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html . Everything works well for local built in client. Now I want to to be able to access it from external apps, not part of any kubernetes environment.

Comment: If you want to access a secure deployment from outside kubernetes, you'll need to reduce the ssl level to skip host checking and even ignore the CA if you don't have the ca.crt.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out how to do this by picking up the certificates I generated for the local sql client and re-using them in my node app - like this

```
const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'xxxx',
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
  port:26257,
  user:"root",
  database:"xxxx",
  ssl : {
      rejectUnauthorized : false,
      ca   : fs.readFileSync("./ca/ca.crt").toString(),
      key  : fs.readFileSync("./ca/client.xxxx.key").toString(),
      cert : fs.readFileSync("./ca/client.xxxx.crt").toString()
  }

});
```

I exposed the public pod as a service in kubernetes like this

```
kubectl expose service cockroachdb-public --port=26257 --target-port=26257 --name=cp --type=LoadBalancer
```

and picked up the external ip address that eventually got assigned to the service.

Pretty straightforward actually, but head scratching when you approach it for the first time. Thanks to those that took the time to comment.

@samstride just noticed your comment. Probably better to use a user other than root, but you can get these certs like this (probably other ways too).

ca (using the cockroachdb-client-secure pod if you still have it running)

```
kubectl exec cockroachdb-client-secure -it -- cat /cockroach-certs/ca.crt  > ./ca.crt
```

key

```
kubectl get secret default.client.root -o jsonpath='{.data.key}' | base64 --decode > client.root.key
```

cert

```
kubectl get secret default.client.root -o jsonpath='{.data.cert}' | base64 --decode > client.root.crt
```

Comment: Is this _really_ the best way to do it? You've made the port publicly accessible. Seems like it could be abused. I assume nodeJS is running inside the cluster, which means exposing the port to the internet is unnecessary...

Comment: Yes you’re quite right. The api and database run in the private kubernetes cluster, and can communicate in that environment, with the api exposed via àn ingress service, and the dB  not at all exposed. This is just to be able to get a dB connection to a dev dB from an external dev environment or dB  client such as postico.

Comment: Hi, I'm in a similar situation

- I have a DEV DB cluster on GCP Kubernetes Engine setup using the documentation at [link](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html)
- I have run "kubectl expose service cockroachdb-public ..." to create a loadbalancer and to be publicly available

I have code on my local machine and I need to get 3 files to be able to connect to the DB

- ca.crt, client.key, client.crt

Can you please share how you did this "by picking up the certificates I generated for the local sql client".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bruce thanks for sharing how to get the key and cert. Seems like cockroach DB managed service is doing the same thing now so that people who use their managed service can connect to the DB from outside the cluster. Will be good to know if they are actually doing what you did or if there is a different/better way to achieve the same end result.

Comment: @samstride I've documented the entire process of setting up a secure cockroachdb on Kubernetes with a collection of scripts. See steps 9-16 for all about user certificates. http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/cloudplatform/cockroachsecurekube